# Flutter qrImage convert to Image

Tags: image, dart, flutter, qr-code

I'm using [qr_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/qr_flutter) to create QrImage. It's ok but I would like to convert QrImage into image in order to create a PDF file to print on the printer. Please kindly help!

```
QrImage(
  data: qrString,
  size: 300.0,
  version: 10,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
),
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [`RepaintBoundary`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RepaintBoundary-class.html) widget with a key to export the widget to a a b64 string which then you can export as an image.

Example:

```
Future<Uint8List> _getWidgetImage() async {
 try {
   RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      _renderObjectKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
   ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
   ByteData byteData =
      await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
   var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
   var bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
   debugPrint(bs64.length.toString());
   return pngBytes;
 } catch (exception) {}
```

}

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
          RepaintBoundary(
            key: _renderObjectKey,
            child: QrImage(
            data: "some text",
            size: 300.0,
            version: 10,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
         ),
       ),
       RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
         _getWidgetImage();
       })
     ]));
```

}

Comment: I was writing the same answer, testing my answer took a little bit time, you won! If I have time in the future I will write another answer that tries to use `QrPainter` class in the plugin and use the `PictureRecorder` class to record canvas result from it.

Answer (score 8):

```
Future<Uint8List> toQrImageData(String text) async {
  try {
    final image = await QrPainter(
      data: text,
      version: QrVersions.auto,
      gapless: false,
      color: hexToColor('#000000'),
      emptyColor: hexToColor('#ffffff'),
    ).toImage(300);
    final a = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    return a.buffer.asUint8List();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more updated typed answer, that adds responsibility seggregation and null-safety, extending [the correct one from @Zroq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080815/5585371) would be:

```
  Future<Uint8List> createImageFromRenderKey({GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>? renderKey}) async {
    try {
      final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = renderKey?.currentContext?.findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;
      final ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3);
      final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

      return byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
    } catch(_) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

The idea is based on the same principle: using the global render key to create the `ByteData` that allows you to create the `Uint8List` buffer. However, the new versions of Flutter change the type of the boundary to become a `RenderyObject?` instead of a `RenderRepaintBoundary`.

The `rethrow` is (dirty) way of bypassing the limitation/small bug where `RepaintBoundary` may be being used in the UI to repaint the boundary (exposed as `boundary.debugNeedsPaint`), so it can potentially throw an unhandled exception or create a low-quality image buffer. So if the view is being used I rethrow the method.
More details about the stack trace: https://github.com/theyakka/qr.flutter/issues/112