# Convert uint8list image to a supported Image file(jpg or etc.)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, uint8array, uint8list

In android 10 and 11 (SDK number 29 and 30) music covers (artworks) formats aren't the same as previous versions, in fact, they aren't readable as a supported image file such as jpg or png, they are uint8lists and only Image.memory widget accepts and shows them.

Now, my problem is I don't wanna read them as a memory image, I need files such as jpg or etc.

Searched a lot! Read a lot and found only 1, not working solution!
And that was writing unit8list as bytes in a file which it's path is ended with ".jpg".
As I said it's not working.

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance, <3.

```
final io.File image = File('directory/image.jpg').create();
image.writeAsBytesSync(uint8list);
```

uint8list sample:[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 226, 2, 40, 73, 67, 67, 95, 80, 82 ,...]

length: thousands

Comment: *"they are uint8lists"* - how you read them? what is their [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078493/flutter-qrimage-convert-to-image
you can read to result

Comment: @sanghuynh I guess you misunderstood my question! I wanna decode unit8list to jpg not encode it!

Comment: @pskink I don't know a lot about uint8lists and only know that it's an encoding method to compress images as a string data.

Comment: @pskink Flutter_audio_query package provides them.

Comment: I'll provide a sample of uint8list in edit.

Comment: @pskink sample of uint8list added.

Comment: your uint8list is a valid image data, if `Image.memory` can decode it then `Image.file` will do work too if you write your data correctly

Comment: Have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63732653/8342742) if this could help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write Uint8list as a file, you can use `File(String).writeAsBytes(Uint8list);`. You can set the path and file extension on the File object and pass the image bytes on [writeAsBytes()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html)

```dart
Uint8List imageBytes;
File('image.jpg').writeAsBytes(imageBytes);
```

Comment: you have any idea, how to write Uint8List as Image data type in flutter

Comment: If you're pertaining to the Image widget, you can use [Image.memory(Uint8List)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html)

Comment: No, I'm not using that in widget..

Comment: How did you know the format of the image, that you want to end the the `path` with like `.jpg` `.png`...etc.